# Should I compare with None explicitly

Tags: python, nonetype

I have a relatively simple Python code:

```
import threading

class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self._thread = None

    def start(self):
        self._thread = threading.Thread(...)

    def stop(self):
        if self._thread:
            ...
```

A colleague suggested that I should compare with `None` explicitly in `stop` function: `if self._thread is not None:`

I am not sure which version is more Pythonic: the implicit or explicit check? Also, if I use any other type (apart from collections, which when evaluated in boolean context test for emptiness) should I compare to `None` explicitly?

Comment: If your variable could hold an int, or any other not-None value that can be falsey, then you might have to check `None` explicitly. Otherwise, you can use the implicit boolean conversion. That's what it's there for.

Comment: Depends on your use case.Sometimes its necessary, others it's irrelevant

Comment: Could `self._thread` ever conceivably contain any other *falsey* value, and would that make any difference to your logic…? If the answer is *no*, then it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: In this particular case, `self._thread` is either `None` or an instance of `threading.Thread`. In more general case I was thinking of a variable being `None` or instance of any class type (but not a collection).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the values your variable may take and the expectations your code has. If your variable may take on other *falsey* values, then yes, the difference between `None` and, say, `[]` may be significant and you need to explicitly check for `is None`.

But not always. What if your value is a *falsey* `[]`, and you're writing an `if foo:` to decide whether you have a value that needs processing? Well, an empty list might not need processing either, since it's empty. So both `None` and `[]` can be treated the same. In this case you'd need to explicitly check for `is None` *and* and empty list, in which case `if foo:` already encapsulates both very succinctly.

In your case, if the variable can be either `None` or a `Thread`, there's no difference whether you add `is not None` or not, it will behave identically in both cases. So why make it more verbose than it needs to be?

There's no one rule that fits all situations.

Comment: as long as the user doesn't tries to access a function / parameter of Thread in that if condition this code it's perfectly valid.